# quote delimiter in substr oracle

Tags: oracle

I would like to know how to mix up the function substr and quotes delimiter in sql query.
such query send me the error invalid query

```
SQL>Insert into employee (name) 
values(substr(q'<ALEXANDRE SA'A DONJUAN LA FAMILLE ANDREA>',1,20));
```

I expect this query to insert the name as **ALEXANDRE SA'A DONJU**
thank you to help me

Comment: Your query is fine except for the missing bracket at the end.

Comment: @EatÅPeach There's no missing bracket, or am I missing something? (edit: I guess you're talking about the ')', not the '>' ?)

Comment: I corrected the query so don't worry and thanks  a lot for your contribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of the quote operator `q` and `substr` is fine - you're just missing a closing `)`:

```
Insert into employee (name) 
  values(substr(q'<ALEXANDRE SA'A DONJUAN LA FAMILLE ANDREA>',1,20));
```

Comment: You missed out on one detail with "<" and "<", should be twice the same: ">". There is difference between: select q'>Oracle's quote operator<' from dual; and select q'>Oracle's quote operator>' from dual;. First doesn't work.

Comment: @Franek That's not correct. Oracle's quote operator has special handling for brackets `[`, `{`, `<` and `(`, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm

Comment: You are right. I apologize. Example in my previous comment is inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

after changing to propera usage of quote operator:

```
Insert into employee (name) 
 values(substr(q'>ALEXANDRE SA'A DONJUAN LA FAMILLE ANDREA>',1,20));
```

Comment: Thank's for voting down, I did not know the quote operator.

Comment: I expect this query to insert the name as ALEXANDRE SA'A DONJU

Comment: While this works, I find your usage of `>` as a quote delimiter quite confusing. IMHO, it's better to either use opening/closing brackets (see my answer) or something completely different, e.g. `#`

Answer (score 0):

## Its Working You can run This

```
Insert into employee (name) 
 values(substr(q'[ALEXANDRE SA'A DONJUAN LA FAMILLE ANDREA']',1,20));
```